# Data formatting of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I got an array like below -

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'Benefits',
    coverage: [{
      name: "item_one",
      interest: [{
        name: "interest_one",
        limit: [{
          value: 2000
        }]
      }],
      limit: [{
        value: "Y"
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'Benefits',
    coverage: [{
      name: "item_two",
      interest: [{
        name: "interest_two",
        limit: [{
          value: 5000
        }]
      }],
      limit: [{
        value: "Y"
      }]
    }]
  }
]
```

I need to display benefit in the frontend. but the problem is when i'm mapping through this array the benefits prints twice. I know there are two objects that is why it is printing twice.

So i decided to convert this array to like below

```js
const arr2 = [{
  name: 'Benefits',
  oneCoverage: [{
    name: "item_one",
    interest: [{
      name: "interest_one",
      limit: [{
        value: 2000
      }]
    }],
    oneLimit: [{
      value: "Y"
    }]
  }],
  twoCoverage: [{
    name: "item_two",
    interest: [{
      name: "interest_two",
      limit: [{
        value: 5000
      }]
    }],
    limit: [{
      value: "Y"
    }]
  }]
}]
```

But no success in getting the above data.

I want to convert `arr` to `arr2` format.

How can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using `reduce`. I treat this as grouping problem where I group by `name`. But here I had to assume that every `coverage` is an array of 1 element.
Maybe you were stuck with creating the key name like `oneCoverage` and so on.
That can be handled by `${coverage[0].name.split("_")[1]}Coverage`

In the end I take the values array using `Object.values`

```js
const arr = [{    name: 'Benefits',    coverage: [{      name: "item_one",      interest: [{        name: "interest_one",        limit: [{          value: 2000        }]      }],      limit: [{        value: "Y"      }]}]  },  {    name: 'Benefits',    coverage: [{      name: "item_two",      interest: [{        name: "interest_two",        limit: [{          value: 5000        }]      }],      limit: [{        value: "Y"      }]    }]  }]

const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc,{name,coverage}) => {
  acc[name] ??= {name}
  const keyName = `${coverage[0].name.split("_")[1]}Coverage`
  acc[name][keyName] = coverage
  return acc
}, {}))

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: will reduce not modifies the original array

Comment: no here your original array stays as it is

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

```js
const arr2 = [{
  name: 'Benefits', // or arr[0].name
  oneCoverage: arr[0].coverage,
  twoCoverage: arr[1].coverage,
}]
```

If you need deep clone, you can use:

```js
const arr2 = [{
  name: 'Benefits', // or arr[0].name
  oneCoverage: structuredClone(arr[0].coverage),
  twoCoverage: structuredClone(arr[1].coverage),
}]
```

However, I can't see any "benefit" of arr2's structure, my advice is:

```js
const benefits = [];
arr.filter((v) => v.name === 'Benefits').forEach((v) => {
  benefits.push(...structuredClone(v.coverage))
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(benefits));
/**
[
  {
    "name": "item_one",
    "interest": [{
      "name": "interest_one",
      "limit": [{ "value": 2000 }]
    }],
    "limit": [{ "value": "Y" }]
  },
  {
    "name": "item_two",
    "interest": [{
      "name": "interest_two",
      "limit": [{ "value": 5000 }]
    }],
    "limit": [{ "value": "Y" }]
  }
]
*/
```

Comment: structuredClone doesn't have all browser support